# How display a popup in pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Using Acrobat Reader we can execute some js in the browsers such as autoprint:

```
window.print();
```

Is it possible to trigger show a fancy popup preferably something that can be styled or at least show a popup message when the pdf is opened *only* in the browser?

I think the `alert` should work, but I'm still thinking if there is a better solution:

```
alert(
 `Note: you're seeing this in
 the browser, but you can save
 it on your local machine using
 CTRL/Command + S`
);
```

Comment: Is your goal to have people download your PDF? If so, why not just add the `download` attribute to the link?

Comment: @vlaz Because when they click the link, the pdf is opened and the print popup appears (because of the injected js from there). The primary goal is that people want to print it, but we want to notify them that it's possible to save the pdf as well.